# Does the domain of a function affect the meaning of limit

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

I recently was reading in stewarts calculus book the definition of limits and continuity.from what I understand for a limit to exsist for a function $f(x)$ at a point a means that
$\lim\limits_{x \to a^{+}} f(x)$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to a^{-}} f(x)$.
However if I had the function say $y=x^2$ and I restricted its domain so that it was $-2\leq x \leq 2$. If I was to say that the $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} x^2 = 4$ is this incorrect as the function is not defined for x greater than $2$ however since the functions domain does not consider values of x greater than $2$ then is it true that only the one sided limit is needed.my question is if the domain of a function has been restricted than can we consider the limit at its end point defined and to be the true limit not one sided as $x$ approaches the end point from within the domain?.

Answer (score 1):

The rule “$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists if and only $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ both exist and they are equal” holds when (and only when) there are points in the domain of $f$ arbitrarily close to $a$ and smaller than $a$ and there are points in the domain of $f$ arbitrarily close to $a$ and greater than $a$. So, it doesn't apply to $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ when the domain of $f$ is $[-2,2]$. In this case, there is no $\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)$ and then$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x).$$

Comment: So indeed the limit is 4?

Comment: Yes, it is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

You could take this definition of a limit:

Take a function $f:X\subset\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ then for $a\in X'$ (the set of accumulation points of X) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if for every sequence $\lbrace x_n\rbrace\subset X\setminus \lbrace a\rbrace$ $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=L$.

If you take a point $a$ in the interior of the domain then the definition above implies that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Often, at end or boundary points of a domain on a closed interval, the definition of a limit is tweaked to only require approaching from the side of the domain.

In this case or interpretation, the limit is indeed 4.

But I have seen a few or some texts say the limit does not exist, particularly, when applying the limit definition of the derivative at the endpoint of a domain.